# What are the challenges of living on a planet with constant meteor showers?

Tags: planets, astronomy, weather, natural-disasters, extinction

I have been thinking of a planet that has or is experience(ing) a lunar holocaust; moon broke into pieces and many of them fell to the planet. Initial disasters probably caused a *massive* mass-extinction event I'm certain, but I ask if life managed to eke itself out, what would its challenges be towards redeveloping complex life? Part of the moon still remains, but I also assume that a lesser chunk would create tidal disasters which I am thinking about on my own - it's irrelevant. However, what *is* also important is the fact general meteor strikes unrelated to the moon pieces would increase dramatically without a moon to take them in. This isn't a singular massive strike (yet) so assume the planet maintains its orbit, atmosphere, and oceans.

I'm not asking if life COULD exist on this planet - I intend to **make it** exist somehow. The question remains, what does that life have to overcome?
If this is a challenge without a solution, let it be known that I tried.

Comment: Possibly the K-T event will be a good model.  https://www.britannica.com/science/K-T-extinction  It was probably one big smack followed by a bunch of various sized smacks at irregular intervals.

Answer (score 3):

**Ocean refuge**

Your premise is the one in [Seveneves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seveneves) - moon breaks apart.  The thing about having moon chunks fall to Earth is the same principle as the Chicxulub meteor - that extinction event occurred because the atmosphere was superheated.  The meteor (or more properly pieces of earth and meteor thrown into the sky by the impact) comes back and heats the air.  Things that had to breathe outside air on that hot day died.  Things that could hide underwater or underground for a full day did not die.

Your moon catastrophe will be similar.  In Seveneves the atmosphere was hot for thousands of years.

In your world, if the oceans are as big as earth, waterbreathing life undersea might be fine.  You can have complex life come back that way.    More meteor impacts after the initial events are not super problematic for undersea life.

Maybe you want a bigger extinction event, Permian style.  Then your life will regenerate from [priapulid worms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priapulida) the ultimate survivors.  I think regardless, priapulid worms should have a strong supporting role in your story.

Comment: Oh shoot! I didn't know someone wrote something like this. I am looking more into the millions of years range to see what species could evolve on a planet like that, really.

(One minor unrelated correction, the KT Extinction happened because the planet actually got colder, not hotter. The ash thrown into the air caused too much sunlight to reflect back into space. Opposite greenhouse effect. Look up the 1815 eruption of Mount Tambora for a fascinating and somewhat scary way this happened in our own time on the small scale (globally).)

Comment: @Quinn - dont sweat it.  His premise is an Armageddon style thing set on Earth.  Yours is a different world long after the event.  It is all good.  Plus maybe it is good for high SF to not be the absolute first to propose some concept.    I will note that Seveneves did not have any priapulid worms, so you could be the first one to showcase those.

Answer (score 0):

Your intention for it to last for millions of years is the problem, assuming a habitable planet, you have something creating new debris. The planet being disturbed and flung into an orbit that aligns with an asteroid belt might work, its irregular orbit allowing for passes to ensnare objects in a low-density asteroid field?  Would likely need to be a small system with two suitable orbits near the star.

It would not be a regular event but a large moon being struck and creating temporary rings might allow for some interesting events too. Or if things got crazy and something disturbed the orbit, causing the planet to be sent into a new orbital trajectory and somehow causing the moon to be obliterated. If modeled right, it could mean that the planet drifts in and out of the debris field and while inching into it bit by bit over tens of thousands of years. Pulling more and more of the old moon planet-side as it does so. Millions of years need to go by to absorb it all then.

Comment: The idea was actually that the planet had two moons that collided with each other. Most of that debris went encircling the planet. As large pieces of the moons disintegrate, more of it falls over the course of those years. There's certainly enough debris in two moons to fuel magnified meteorite activity for a significant amount of geological time. Tidal forces will cause chunks to break evenly over time. I will say that if our moon did not exist we would be experiencing SIGNIFICANTLY more meteor activity. It might not be regular, but enough for meteors to prompt evolution is my goal here.

Comment: 65 Mya comes to mind for some reason... Jokes aside, when you said over millions of years, I took it as several planet-wide events occurring several tens or hundreds of thousands of years apart.  Any chance you have seen Artifexians' If Earth had Rings : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CItDiuBWP5I  - Earth wouldn't work, but it'd be cool if it did.